# sencha touch - how to read the multiple json object (response of ajax) in initcomponent of panel

Tags: ajax, json, sencha-touch, storage, iteration

Need to read the multiple json object that got form ajax request . I have used the code given below. Its taking too long time . so other codes are executed prior to this code.

```
var allVisitStore =  new Ext.data.Store({ 
model: 'allVisit',
autoLoad : true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    id: 'allvisit_app_localstore',
    url: '/RadMobApp/api',
    extraParams:{          
        action:'test',
        queryName:'GET_ALL_TEST',
        username:'1234',
        password:'1234',
        retFormat:'XML',
        patTicketId: '4098'
        keyValuePair:'yes'
    },
    // the return will be XML, so lets set up a reader
    reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
        // records will have an "T4" tag
        record: 'data'
    })
}
```

});

is there any alternative method for the above

Answer (score 0):

All Ajax requests in Sencha Touch, and indeed ExtJS are Asynchronous.
You need to do whatever you need to do when the store loads

Listen to the stores 'load' event and then continue processing.

You can add a listener in the store config like this:

```
var allVisitStore =  new Ext.data.Store({ 
model: 'allVisit',
autoLoad : true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    id: 'allvisit_app_localstore',
    url: '/RadMobApp/api',
    extraParams:{          
        action:'query',
        queryName:'GET_ALL_VISIT',
        username:'superuser',
        password:'superuser',
        retFormat:'XML',
        patTicketId: 'PAT-4098'
        keyValuePair:'yes'
    },
    // the return will be XML, so lets set up a reader
    reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
        // records will have an "T4" tag
        record: 'data'
    }),
    listeners : {
        'load' : function(){

            // call code here that should be run when the data has returned

        }
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
allVisitStore.on('load',function(){
// call code here that should be run when the data has returned
```

});

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have used like this but no any result it doesn't store any value. Is there any other way to do this